# The Walking Dead not loading

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

I recently bought season 1 & 2 of the walking dead for my computer and I started loading up season 1. I clicked to continue but then it just said connecting and it's been going like that for a while now. Has that happened to anyone else and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Checked firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not an official bug hence there is no official solution/fix for this. Many people encounter this issue, but many people not.

 [Here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/207610/discussions/0/846958223145969370/?l=french) is a discussion of those people faced this problem and some fix.

 Some solutions may or may not work. 
 So I wish you luck with one of the solutions mentioned in the link.